# Best method for handling lots of strings from an xml in an Android app?

Tags: android, xml, string, performance

I'm developing an Android app which displays a list of objects. For each object displayed I populate several textviews with information stored in strings members.

The information is stored in separate xml files with the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <string-array name="Object_Name">
       <!-- Atribute 1 -->
       <item ></item>
       <!-- Atribute 2 -->
       <item ></item>
       <!-- Atribute 3 -->
       <item ></item>
       <!-- Atribute 4 -->
       <item ></item>
       <!-- Atribute 5 -->
       <item ></item>
       <!-- Atribute 6 -->
       <item ></item>
       <!-- Atribute 7 -->
       <item ></item>
       <!-- Atribute 8 -->
       <item ></item>
       <!-- Atribute 9 -->
       <item ></item>
   </string-array>

</resources>
```

I have thought of two ways to handle this the information in my app:

1. When the application starts, I create a list of objects and for each `</string-array>` I have defined in my xml files. I store in the object members the strings from the `<item>`. There are around 250 such objects and some of the attributes contain large strings(1000 characters or more). Every time the textviews need to be populated I read the strings from the objects with getter methods.
2. When the application starts, I create a list of objects and for each `</string-array>` I have defined in my xml files. I store the resource id for the `</string-array>` but don't read any attribute. Every time the textviews need to be populated, I read the attributes from the xml associated with the object and return the strings.

The first method impacts the app startup because it takes a bit of time to populate the list of objects with the information from the array but has the benefit of speed once the list is created. Also all those strings might need quite a bit of memory and memory is a precious resource on smartphones.

The second method will reduce the app startup and use less memory for the list of objects, because only resource id's are stored. The drawback I see is that every time the textviews are created and populated, the contents is read from the xml files. I assume that reading from the storage medium, takes longer time and might make the app feel sluggish to the user.

Is my analysis of the two methods correct or not?

Which method do you think I should use and why?

Are there some tools that I can use to measure runtime and memory usage?

Comment: Since you have lot of data to display and you are storing this all data in seperate xml files. This is not the proper way to store static strings. You can use SQLite Database to store that much of data. While using Database also you can access data very smoothly and it took very less time to load all data.

Comment: You mean to store the data into an SQLite Database instead of the xml or populate a database at the startup from the xml? Are there any tools to populate the database offline before I include it in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have lot of data to display and you are storing this all data in seperate xml files. This is not the proper way to store static strings. You can use SQLite Database to store that much of data. While using Database also you can access data very smoothly and it took very less time to load all data.

To avoid memory and performances issues you need to use Database.

Yes you can use Database offline in device.

Check below link to use SQLite database
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: Using database is the best option to store and load large amount of data with speed and best performance.

Comment: I have the tables prepared in the database and now I am working on a small java program to parse the xml files and create the sql commands to populate the database with the information.

Comment: why you have need to parse xml data? If data is static then once you add the static entries into database manually. Once you inserted the data into database. You can use this database anywhere and you have not need to parse xml files always.

Answer (score 0):

The best method id List view , coz once you keep a a list view in xml you can give n number of values in java, associated to that list view

Comment: I use a ViewPager to display fragments for each object. I can't store that many ListViews in layout xmls.